# How do I convert numeric words to a phone numbers beginner style?

Tags: python, numbers

**Problem:**

I'm a beginner (3 months) at Python programming, my school assignment asks me to take a text-file with numeric words (e.g.: three oh five nine ...) and convert this to phone numbers (see list below) in a separate file. I've been thinking my brain off and can't find a simple, beginner-friendly style to write a code for this. I would appreciate some help.

**My IPO plan is as follows:**

**Input:**
Open the text-file in read mode.

**Processing:**
Split the text-file into words in a list.
Convert each word to its corresponding number.
Display each number in a string.

**Output:**
Print the string containing the phone number.

I can't seem to convert my plan into a code.

*The Input is a file which looks as follows:*

- two three seven oh nine eight oh
- eight one eight four three seven two nine six three
- one five oh three four seven seven two five seven two
- two nine six two three five oh
- five two oh four four seven nine eight two one
- one eight oh oh five five five one two one two
- four three seven two nine six three

***EDIT: The problem has been solved and this is the final (working) code:**

```
di = {"oh":0,"one":1,"two":2,"three":3,"four":4,"five":5,"six":6,"seven":7,"eight":8,"nine":9}
c=""

infile=open("digit_words.txt","r")
outfile=open("digit_strings.txt","w")

l=infile.readlines()

for line in l:
    words=line.split()

    for nos in words:
        c+=str(di[nos])

    print(c, file=outfile)
    print("\n")
    c=""

infile.close()
outfile.close()}
```

*The matching output is another file that looks as follows:*

- 2370980
- 8184372963
- 15034772572
- 2962350
- 5204479821
- 18005551212
- 4372963

Comment: Does the file really contain `oh` or `zero`? Either way try creating a dictionary to map and update the text: `d = {'zero': 0, 'one': 1, 'two': 2 . . . 'nine': 9}`

Comment: Your plan looks good to me. Would suggest concentrating on the individual parts you have already identified, such as 1st: read line from file, 2nd: split line into words. If you search for those individual parts I'm sure you'll be able to find something helpful to guide you. Good luck!

Comment: @It_is_Chris Yes, my professor really asked us to refer to 'zero' as 'oh', but I guess I can incorporate that into the list very easily. Thank you for the dictionary tip!

Comment: @4D45 Thank you, I will sure do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let's change your plan to code. Let's assume that the file name is phno.txt, your code would be:

```
di= {"zero":0,"one":1,"two":2,"three":3,"four":4,"five":5,"six":6,"seven":7,"eight":8,"nine":9}
c=""
f=open("phno.txt","r")
l=f.readlines()
for line in l:
    words=line.split()
    for nos in words:
         c+=str(di[nos])
    print(c)
    print("\n")
    c=""
```

Comment: Thank you so much Abhijit! This makes it much more clear. I do have another question in regards to the for-statement. Since I get my input from a file, shouldn't I make use of sys.stdin? Such as the following: 'For line in sys.stdin:' etc. Or will the 'l=f.readlines()' be sufficient to go through all the number in the list and process them?

Comment: @sylllx you unaccepted my answer?? Can I know the reason?? If there's some mistake, I'll rectify

Comment: Hi @Abhijit Shirwal, yes I didn't want to raise any confusion for other readers. i thought it worked but after running your code it didn't. I changed it up a little bit and it works better, the only problem is the output is wrong and 1 long string instead of separate phone numbers. Please do help me, I put my code in the question section above.

Comment: I thought there was only one number, update c=" " when the line is finished. Remember only one phone number should be there in one single line, let me edit my code, try and let me know if you got you output. Accept my answer again if it worked

Comment: Oh my goodness! With a few tweaks it worked, I'll update my final (working) code. Thanks for clarifying the fact that the original only worked with one number, I guess I learned something new. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Glad to help, even more happy when I read "learned something new" 

Answer (score -2):

```
# pip install word2number
from word2number import w2n
print w2n.word_to_num("two million three thousand nine hundred and eighty four")
# 2003984
```

Improving the library to a custom number can be using this

```
word2number.w2n.american_number_system
{'zero': 0, 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5, 'six': 6, 'seven': 7, 'eight': 8, 'nine': 9, 'ten': 10, 'eleven': 11, 'twelve': 12, 'thirteen': 13, 'fourteen': 14, 'fifteen': 15, 'sixteen': 16, 'seventeen': 17, 'eighteen': 18, 'nineteen': 19, 'twenty': 20, 'thirty': 30, 'forty': 40, 'fifty': 50, 'sixty': 60, 'seventy': 70, 'eighty': 80, 'ninety': 90, 'hundred': 100, 'thousand': 1000, 'million': 1000000, 'billion': 1000000000, 'point': '.'}

word2number.w2n.american_number_system['oh']=0
word_to_num('oh') # 0 (zero)
```

Comment: Thats incorrect mostly because python was made to improve extension methods and if you would like to customize a library, mistery solved, you can @ValerijDobler. Thank you for helping to improve my question and prove that your unfriendly comment can be a better thing into the world

Comment: @Franz: it is best to avoid retaliating if you can. The comment above is excessively spiky, but it is ideal to either address the content of it, or ignore it. You can always flag as "no longer needed" if you think it should be removed (I will do that now).